# Unable to instantiate view programmatically

Tags: swift

I have created a component (swift + xib file)

```
@IBDesignable
class MainItem: UIView {
    let kCONTENT_XIB_NAME = "MainItem";

    @IBOutlet weak var newsImage: UIImageView!;
    @IBOutlet weak var newsTitle: UILabel!;

    @IBInspectable var image:UIImage? {
        didSet {
            if(image != nil && newsImage != nil) {
                newsImage.image = image;
            }
        }
    };

    @IBInspectable var title:String = "" {
        didSet {
             newsTitle.text = title;
        }
    };

    required init?(coder aDecoder: NSCoder) {
        super.init(coder: aDecoder)
        commonInit()
    }

    override init(frame: CGRect) {
        super.init(frame: frame)
        commonInit()
    }


//    override func viewDidLoad(){
//        super.viewDidLoad();
//    }

    func loadViewFromNib() -> UIView? {
        let nib = UINib(nibName: kCONTENT_XIB_NAME, bundle: nil)
        return nib.instantiate(withOwner: self, options: nil).first as? UIView
    }

    func commonInit() {
        // standard initialization logic
        guard let view = loadViewFromNib() else { return }
        view.frame = self.bounds
        self.addSubview(view)

        if(newsImage != nil) {
            let bounds = CGRect.init(x: newsImage.frame.origin.x,
                                 y: newsImage.frame.origin.y + (newsImage.frame.height / 2),
                                 width: newsImage.frame.width,
                                 height: newsImage.frame.height / 2)

            newsImage.addBlackGradientLayerInBackground(frame: bounds, colors:[.clear, .black])
        }
    }
}
```

The xib I have done with one tutorial, I have connected the file owner to the class also the IBOutlets are connected. And this worked fine, if I use this component within a storyboard.

Now I am trying to use this in my code

```
func initSlider() -> [MainItem] {

        let slide1 = UINib(nibName: "MainItem", bundle: nil).instantiate(withOwner: nil, options: nil)[0] as! MainItem

        slide1.image = UIImage(named: "u17119.png")
        slide1.title = "bla bla"

        return [slide1];
    }
```

I am getting this error on startup

> *** Terminating app due to uncaught exception 'NSUnknownKeyException', reason: '[ setValue:forUndefinedKey:]: this class is not key value coding-compliant for the key newsImage.'

I am not shure why this is comming

Also a side note:

If I uncomment the `viewDidLoad` section in my component - I can't compile

> Method does not override any method from its superclass
>   Value of type 'UIView' has no member 'viewDidLoad'

Answer (score 1):

It will be useful for you to understand how the code works in your first (working) example. There are *two* views in the story: the MainItem declared in your code, and the UIView designed in the *MainItem.xib* file. They are *different!* The one declared in code is the MainItem. The one in the *.xib* is just a plain vanilla UIView.

In the *.xib* file, the File's Owner is declared as being a MainItem. Therefore the File's Owner sprouts `newsImage` and `newsTitle` outlets, and these are hooked to subviews of the UIView in the *.xib* file.

When the MainItem is initialized, it reaches into the *.xib* file and loads the UIView *with itself* (the MainItem) *as owner*. This matches the situation with the outlets, so the outlets are correctly hooked up. And then it plops the UIView into itself as its own subview, with exactly the same size. Thus it acts a host to the UIView.

Let's chart that architecture:

```
MainItem view --> subview --> xib file UIView
    newsImage outlet --------> UIImageView subview
    newsTitle outlet --------> UILabel subview
```

The point is, that is the *only* architecture under which this *xib* file is capable of operating correctly.

So in your second example, you attempt to use a completely different architecture. You are no longer in the MainItem; you are in a UIViewController. And you attempt to reach directly into the *xib* yourself and load the UIView *with `nil` as owner*, and with no MainItem to host it. You completely bypass the MainItem and the loading architecture that it establishes! Thus the outlets cannot be hooked up and you crash.

Answer (score -1):

I think that the problem is related to "Bundle" that it must be the "main". So you can try this:

```
NSBundle.mainBundle().loadNibNamed("MainItem", owner: self, options: nil)
```

also check that Module is refers to your target (check in Xib View, top right, under the class field).

Furthermore, pay attention to using "!" because force cast can bring a crash, use "?" optional operator.